# sass bem element modifier inheriting said elements properties

Tags: css, sass, bem

I know that sass provides us with @extend method that allows me to do this:

```
%knob {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
}

.house {
  &__door {
    &__knob {
      color: inherit;
      @extend %knob;

      &--red {
        @extend %knob;
        // $1
        color: red;
      }

      &--blue{
        @extend %knob;
        // $1
        color: blue;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

however i would prefer not to define abstract class `%knob` at all, would it be possible to reference/include properties defined in `__knob` (width and height in this case) from within its modifiers `--red` and `--blue`?

im including sassmeister snippet here to help out a bit: http://sassmeister.com/gist/58b5b4673a18ecadbba7

example here might not look like an issue but if an element with a long class name has 2 or more different groups of modifiers, and I wont create an abstract class, i sometimes end up with html tags looking like this `<p class="some other classes some-house__some-door__some-knob some-house__some-door__some-knob--red">example</p>` which I find not very desirable.

#### what i would like to achieve:

referencing parent element would alow me to reduce this string to `<p class="some other classes some-house__some-door__some-knob--red"></p>` without necessity of declaring an abstract `%knob` class

#### why am I hesitant about using an abstract class here:

declaring an abstract class inside `__door` element (http://sassmeister.com/gist/bc49e0885342e96a8fbd) gives me this result:

```
.house__door .house__door__knob, .house__door .house__door__knob--red, .house__door .house__door__knob--blue {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
}
```

instead of desired

```
.house__door__knob, .house__door__knob--red, .house__door__knob--blue {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
}
```

and declaring an abstract class outside of the scope its going to be used in makes the code less readable

or maybe theres a different apporach i could use in order to make my code more readable/maintainable?

Comment: What's wrong with what you already have, exactly?

Comment: why do you need to `@extend %knob` on the modifiers? wouldn't they inherit %knob styles (width, height in this case) from `.house__door__knob` ? As you are including all the classes in your html element

Comment: updated the question with what i would like to achieve. I'm not sure wether this would be a good/better approach but its something i'd might like to try, as I'm not entirely sure why would modifiers not extend its parent element by default

Comment: You haven't explained what's wrong with what you already have.  Your existing Sass code already lets you write your markup the way you want.

Comment: well yes, this works, but ability to reference parent element would allow me not to define an abstract class at all

Comment: i've updated the question again

Comment: Why is it a problem that the selector you're extending is at the root of the document rather than nested inside your `.house` selector?

Comment: I dont want to define this abstract class at all, as I dont see the reason why would this be necessary. About your question - it makes it less readable, also defining the class itself unnecessairly pollutes namespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

while searching for an answer to my question i came to the conclusion that inheriting parent element properties/ using @extend or @include here might not be the best idea as it would work well only if an element had 1 modification at most:

in other cases if multiple modifications extended same model, and were to be used to the same html element, all of the base properties would be declared multiple times

also there is no need at all to deeply nest elements (i.e. `foo__bar__baz`). separating elements makes code easier to maintain.